# Why is my android phone portscanning my PC?

Tags: windows, malware, firewall

I have bitdefender whining about my PC being portscanned.
The logs show that it is coming from my android phone (which has static address).

[image]

Is that normal?
How can i figure out the app that is doing this?

Asked over at the superuser forums but it was suggested that here i could get more detailed information.

Comment: I don't think there's much we can say without knowing what the actual behaviour is that triggered the warning. Do you have any apps that have features for sharing data on a LAN, such as SHAREit or SE File Explorer?

Comment: I have file commander which has such an option, but i dont have that feature enabled right now. Is there some app for android perhaps that would monitor which app is doing that?